# Disable Advanced Options entry automatic generation in GRUB

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader

Is it possible to instruct GRUB to not include the Advanced Options entry while it routinely updates? I mean this snippet in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which I forced to remove manually every time some package update is requesting GRUB config recreation:

```
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-7abbf46a-25c1-4ac5-b8fc-eff98778e924' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-4-amd64-advanced-7abbf46a-25c1-4ac5-b8fc-eff98778e924' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod lvm
                insmod ext2
                set root='lvmid/iLJBEP-k39n-9Orf-iYFY-szXc-GiFC-hw19FQ/R5kb0j-PEbc-THWn-fH8a-rECU-z7x2-Mr200e'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/iLJBEP-k39n-9Orf-iYFY-szXc-GiFC-hw19FQ/R5kb0j-PEbc-THWn-fH8a-rECU-z7x2-Mr200e'  7abbf46a-25c1-4ac5-b8fc-eff98778e924
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7abbf46a-25c1-4ac5-b8fc-eff98778e924
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/debianvg-mainlv ro  quiet
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
        }
```

The system is Debian Stable (Jessie 8.5) with GRUB version 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1 installed.

Comment: It's only a guess, but if you move the files associated with the advanced submenu, say to `/noboot/`, then I would not expect `grub` to create an empty `Advanced Options` when `update-grub` is called.

Comment: The files responsible are `10_linux` and `30_os-prober` in `/etc/grub.d` but they cannot be removed since they do a lot of a useful stuff.

Comment: If moving the unneeded boot files doesn't work, then you are stuck with editing these files, but it's not a task to embark on lightly.

Comment: Sure, but I wonder if there is some other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add `GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y` to `/etc/default/grub`
- Regenerate the grub configuration: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

See [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Disable_submenu) for more explanations:

> If you have multiple kernels installed, say linux and linux-lts, by default grub-mkconfig groups them in a submenu. If you do not like this behaviour you can go back to one single menu by adding the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:
>
> `GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y`